# Getting number of rows inserted for ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE multiple insert?

Tags: mysql

I have a very large table with a primary key of `BINARY(20)`.

The table has around 17 million rows. Every hour a cron job tries to insert as many as 50,000 new entries into this table with the `ON_DUPLICATE_KEY_UPDATE` syntax.

Each insert in the cronjob is with 1,000 values (multiple insert). How can I get the number of rows inserted into the table from this query? I cannot do a row count before and after as there are around 17million rows and the query is too expensive.

In the manual mysql says for a row inserted the affected number of rows is `1` and for an updated field it is `2`, meaning in my 1000 INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE query I could have affected rows ranging from 1000 - 2000, but I have no way of telling how many records were inserted from this number?

How can I overcome this?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The number of inserts would be 2000 minus the number of affected rows. More generally:

```
(numberOfValuesInInsert * 2) - mysql_affected_rows()
```

**EDIT:**

As [tomas points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10925632/getting-number-of-rows-inserted-for-on-duplicate-key-update-multiple-insert/10925666?noredirect=1#comment82031928_10925666), The [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) actually say:

> With ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, the affected-rows value per row is 1 if the row is inserted as a new row, 2 if an existing row is updated, **and 0 if an existing row is set to its current values**.

[emphasis mine]

Consequently, if setting an existing row to the same values is a possibility, it's impossible to tell how many rows were updated vs. inserted, since two inserts would be indistinguishable from one update with different values + one update with the same values.

Comment: My math isn't the best, I can't get my head round this lol, I'll do some testing, thanks buddy.

Comment: This asnwer assumes that we'll get either 1 or 2 for each row. 

From the MySQL docs:
For INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statements, the affected-rows value per row is 1 if the row is inserted as a new row, 2 if an existing row is updated, and 0 if an existing row is set to its current values

So I think if an existing row is left unchanged, we'll get 0 and this won't work.. :/

Comment: @tomas thanks, I updated the answer. That's unfortunate.

Comment: You can work around it to prevent unchanged row by force update some static columns, let's say updated_date = now() for example.

Answer (score 7):

When Your job does an Insert of 1000 , some are pure Inserts and some are Updates as you have the ON_DUPLICATE_KEY_UPDATE .
Thus you get the first equation

(1) Inserts + Updates = No of rows Inserted( in this case 1000)

I take a simple example where you get a value of 1350 for the my_sql_affected_rows . 
since for an Insert a value of 1 and for update a value of 2 aggregates to my_sql_affected_rows . I get  the following equation .

(2) Inserts + 2 * Updates = my_sql_affected_rows (in this case 1350) .

Subtract (2) - (1) . You get

(3) Updates = my_sql_affected_rows - No of rows Inserted

Updates = 1350 - 1000 ( in this example ).

Updates = 350 .

Substitute value of Updates in equation (1) , you get

Inserts = 650

Thus to get the number of Updates , you only need to use equation (3) directly .

Comment: So this assumed that there are both inserts and updates, which is not always the case. It can be one of the other cases: only inserts, only updates, no inserts or updates. Is it possible to find out the number of pure inserts in these cases?

Comment: Equation (1) is not accurate here because if a row is set to its current values, we get 0. so you'd get: (1) Inserts + Updates + Unchanged = No of rows Inserted. 

that gives 3 variables and makes this unsolvable :/