# How to return the total results insert and replaced when executing INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE

Tags: mysql

I have a procedure that contains a INSERT ..... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE.

If there a way in MySQL to determine the total rows that were inserted and the total rows that were replaced?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10925632/getting-number-of-rows-inserted-for-on-duplicate-key-update-multiple-insert

Answer (score 1):

You can use http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-affected-rows.html after the query.

> For INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE statements, the affected-rows
>   value is 1 if the row is inserted as a new row and 2 if an existing
>   row is updated

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate this using "Records" and "Duplicates". `Records` is the total number of rows affected. `Duplicates` is the number of updates. So `Records - Duplicates` is the number of inserted rows.

For example:

```
mysql> insert into your_table (...) 
    -> select ... from your_other_table 
    -> on duplicate key update ...;
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.00 sec)
Records: 2  Duplicates: 1  Warnings: 0
```

That means that 1 new row was inserted and 1 existing row was updated.

Comment: Correct, I need to the functions to extract these results so I can insert the results into a summery database. I need to store how many records are updated and how many are inserted in a different table. so what function return the total records? and what function the return total Duplicate?