# ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE callback - MySQL

Tags: mysql

When using:

```
INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
```

Is there a callback to tell me how many rows and what changes were made?

I've searched everywhere but can't find any information on this at all.

Comment: Are you inserting just one row or multiple?

Comment: Its multiple but I use it really for the update as opposed ot the insert.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) saids:

> With ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE, the affected-rows value per row is 1 if the row is inserted  as a new row, and 2 if an existing row is updated.

Comment: Ok, I saw that, but what does that actually mean? Can you give an example of how to get the data back? In my case there will never be an insert, only an update if different information.

Comment: INSERT just returns true or false.

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10925632/getting-number-of-rows-inserted-for-on-duplicate-key-update-multiple-insert  it my help you