# get mysql ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE.. count of rows inserted and updated

Tags: php, mysql

Using below query to insert update records:

```
INSERT INTO table (col_a,col_b,col_c,col_d) VALUES (val_a,val_b,val_c,val_d) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE col_d = VALUES(col_d)
```

mySQL reports:

1 row affected per insert,
2 rows affected per update,
0 rows affected per duplicate

Followed link : [Getting number of rows inserted for ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE multiple insert?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10925632/getting-number-of-rows-inserted-for-on-duplicate-key-update-multiple-insert)

but didn't get correct numbers for inserted and updates records.

Is there any way of returning the correct number of inserts, updates and rows skipped (duplicates)?

Comment: which version of MySQL server you are using? Check this one: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=43311

Comment: mysql version is 5.5.28

Answer (score -1):

Thanks overflowers, i worked out on a way.. thanks [mitksoft](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4582675/mitkosoft) for help, used answer given by a user [user3556345](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3556345/user3556345) on another post - [MySQL on duplicate key update + affected row count](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23148574/mysql-on-duplicate-key-update-affected-row-count)

using mysql_info() getting actual records, duplicates and skipped rows and warnings if any

Code below:

```
list($rec, $dupes, $warns) = sscanf(mysql_info($link), "Records: %d Duplicates: %d Warnings: %d"); // courtesy of user at big lake dot com - php.net
$inserts = $total_rows_affected - ($dupes * 2);
$updates = ($total_rows_affected - $inserts)/2;
$skipped = $rec - ($inserts + $updates);
$total = $rec;
```