# How to get the number of rows affected by INSERT ON DUPLICATE using PDO?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Using PHP's PDO with a MySQL database, how do I get the number rows affected by an `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...` statement?

For instance, how would it be done with the following query?

```
INSERT INTO table1(id,a,b,c)
SELECT id,1,2,3 FROM table2 WHERE x=321
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE a=1,b=2,c=3;
```

Comment: The value returned by PDO's `rowCount()` will be 1 for an insert or 2 for an update to an existing row.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski  Yes, I know that MySQL does as you stated per http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-on-duplicate.html, but that does not answer the question.

Comment: What is your code so far, what is expected, what is actually the result?

Comment: @user1032531 UNIQUE keys reference exactly one row. A single insert will never modify more than one. Are you talking about using multiple inserts via `VALUES (...), (...), (...)`?

Comment: The desired results are the number of times a row is either inserted or updated.  The actual results are one more "rows affected" for every time a row has a duplicate and is updated.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10925632/getting-number-of-rows-inserted-for-on-duplicate-key-update-multiple-insert

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski  Your thread from your latest comment seems to be right on, however, still not sure how it will be actually accomplished.  I will first need to obtain `numberOfValuesInInsert` which I don't know is possible.

Comment: Isn't a multiple executed prepared statement with single row `INSERT` an option?

Comment: @user1032531 It would help if you posted an example of the insert statement you're doing. If you did `INSERT INTO (...) VALUES (...),(...),(...),(...)` then `numberOfvaluesInInsert` is 4, since 4 sets were passed to `VALUES`. If you are dynamically building that statement from an array, then the array length is `numberOfValuesInInsert`.

Comment: If you really must have an accurate number, you probably need two queries.  You can run the inserts separately in a transaction: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4920619/1670021, and then run the updates to see how many change (add the two numbers for a total.)  Or use triggers as described by @Quasimodo'sclone.

Comment: Do you mean counts of inserted vs updated? imo, then triggers are probably useful? Are you using auditing of changes currently? If so then could you use that information?

Comment: @RyanVincent auditing could be of general interest to people looking for similar questions. You should provide further description in an answer.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski  I added a sample query.  Thanks

Comment: Oh, you're using `INSERT INTO... SELECT...`. Is the select `table2` static, or is it likely to be updated often? I don't know of a way to determine how many would be inserted from that except to issue a `COUNT()` query against it first with the same `WHERE`, but that may require locking to prevent changes before the `INSERT` is done.

Answer (score 0):

If you get the (possibly generated) SQL code, you could examine the number of inserts to be done by parsing the statement with a regular expression.

Another approach is to define a trigger. In this case you have to set a user defined variable before the execution of the statement and read it via another query after the execution.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `beforeUpdateTABLENAME`
  BEFORE UPDATE ON `tablename` FOR EACH ROW
  SET @updateRowCount = @updateRowCount + 1;
```

Reset row count

```
$connection->exec('SET @updateRowCount = 0;');
```

Execute the INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...
and read the number of updates

```
$result = $conn->query('SELECT @updateRowCount;');
```

Calculate rows affected = row count - updated rows

If you do not want to distinguish between inserts and updates at all, you can trigger on INSERT as well and no calculation is needed.

```
CREATE TRIGGER beforeInsertTABLENAME
  BEFORE INSERT ON `tablename` FOR EACH ROW
  SET @rowsAffectedCount = @rowsAffectedCount + 1;
```